# Ruby code blocks and Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am an extremely new person to Ruby and Chef. I have been trying to wrap my head around the syntax and do some research, but I am sure as you all know unless one knows the terminology, it is hard to find what you are looking for.

I have read up on Ruby code blocks, but the Chef code blocks still confuse me. I see something like this for example:

```
log "a debug string" do
    level :debug
end
```

Which adds "a debug string" to the log. From what I have seen though, it seems to me like it should be represented as:

```
log do |message|
    #some logic
end
```

Chef refers to these as resources. Can someone please help explain the syntax difference and give me some terminology from which I can start to educate myself with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you come from another language (not Ruby), this syntax might seem very strange. Let's break down things.

When calling a method with parameters, in most cases the parentheses are optional:

- `foo(bar)` is equivalent to `foo bar`
- `foo(bar, baz)` is equivalent to `foo bar, baz`

A Ruby block of code can be wrapped in curly braces (`{}`) or inside a `do..end` block and can be passed to a method as its last parameters (but note that there's no comma and if you're using parentheses it goes **after** them. Some examples:

```
foo(bar) { # code here }

foo(bar) do
  # code here
end

foo bar do
  # code here
end

foo do
  # code here
end
```

In some cases, code blocks can receive parameters, but in Chef the resources' blocks never do. Just for reference, the syntax for that is:

```
foo(bar) do |baz, qux|
  baz + qux
end
```

Specifically about Chef resources, their syntax is usually:

```
resource_type(name) do
  attribute1 value1
  attribute2 value2
end
```

This means that, when you say:

```
log "a debug string" do
  level :debug
end
```

you're actually creating a `log` resource whose `name` attribute is set to `"a debug string"`. It can later be referred to (in other resources, for example) using `log[a debug string]`.

AFAIK, the `name` attribute is mandatory for every Chef resource type as it's what makes it unique, and allows you to, among other things, call actions on it after it has been declared.

---

**Side note:** The ruby block is usually optional for a Chef resource. If you do something like:

```
directory "/some/path"
```

Chef will compile that resource using its default attributes (among which is `action :create`), and try to create the named directory using those.

Answer (score 1):

The `do ... end` here is not a usual ruby block statement.

It's a implementation of `DSL (Domain Specific Language)`.

Here's a nice explanation [[1](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/06/dsl-or-not)]:

> there is the concept of an internal DSL, which uses the syntax of an
>   exіsting language, a host language, such as Ruby. The means of the
>   language are used to build constructs resembling a  distinct language.
>   The, already mentioned, Rake uses this to make code like this
>   possible:
>
> ```
> task :codeGen do        
>   # do the code generation      
> end
> ```

Hope that answer your question.

[[1](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/06/dsl-or-not)] : http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/06/dsl-or-not