# what ruby features are used in chef recipes?

Tags: ruby, syntax, chef-infra

I just started using chef and don't know much about ruby.

I have problems understanding the language-syntax used in recipes.

Say, I create a directory in a cookbook in recipes/default.rb like:

```
directory "/home/test/mydir" do
  owner "test"
  mode "0755"
  action :create
  recursive true
end
```

I assume this is part of a valid ruby script. What do lines like `owner "test"` mean? Is this a function call, a variable assignment or something else entirely?

Comment: What documentation you are reading?

Comment: mostly internet: currently http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/first-steps-with-chef.html

Comment: I am also learning, thus to confirm I asked. :)

Comment: It's a function call. That doesn't mean it isn't handled by `method_missing`, though.

Comment: http://docs.opscode.com/resource.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef is written in Ruby and makes an extensive use of Ruby ability to design custom DSL. Almost every chef configuration file is written with a Ruby-based DSL.

This means that in order to use chef effectively you should be familiar with the basic of Ruby syntax including

- Grammar
- Data types (the main difference compared to other languages are Symbols)
- Blocks

You don't need to know a lot about metaprogramming in Ruby.

The case of the code you posted is an excellent example of a Ruby based DSL. Let me explain it a little bit.

```
# Call the method directory passing the path and a block
# containing some code to be evaluated
directory "/home/test/mydir" do

  # chown the directory to the test user
  owner "test"

  # set the permissions to 0555
  mode "0755"

  # create the directory if it does not exists
  action :create

  # equivalent of -p flag in the mkdir
  recursive true

end
```

Blocks are a convenient way to specify a group of operations (in this case create, set permissions, etc) to be evaluated in a single context (in this case in the context of that path).

Comment: Does `owner`,`mode` etc are methods?

Comment: Yes, the all are Ruby methods. In the case of the `owner`, `owner` is the method and `"test"` the `String` parameter.

Comment: I have answered a similar question in the past here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719968/ruby-code-blocks-and-chef/19726723#19726723 Might have some more valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down.

```
directory "/home/test/mydir" do
  ...
end
```

You are just calling a global method defined by Chef called `directory`, passing one argument `"/home/test/mydir"`, and a block (everything between the `do` and `end`).

This block is probably excecuted in a special scope created by Chef in which all of the options (`owner`, `mode`, `action`, etc.) are method.