# Ruby blocks as used in Chef, trouble understanding syntax

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm somewhat new to Ruby, but I've read a lot of tutorials and docs about blocks.  However, I really don't understand the syntax below, which is used in a Chef recipe:

```
template "/etc/profile.d/golang.sh" do
  source "golang.sh.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0755
end
```

How do I parse this out?  what's `template`?  Is it a function that gets passed 2 parameters (`"/etc/profile.d/golang.sh"` and the block)?  Are `source`, `owner`, etc functions as well?

Sorry if this is such an elementary question!

Comment: I have answered this same question more thoroughly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719968/ruby-code-blocks-and-chef/19726723#19726723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered the same question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20569738/123527

```
# Call the method directory passing the path and a block
# containing some code to be evaluated in the given context
template "/etc/profile.d/golang.sh" do

  # Use the ERB template defined at "golang.sh.erb"
  source "golang.sh.erb"

  # chown the file to the user root
  owner "root"
  group "root"

  # set the permissions to 0555
  mode "0755"
end
```

Blocks are a convenient way to specify a group of operations (in this case create, set permissions, etc) to be evaluated in a single context (in this case in the context of that path).

`template`, `source`, `owner`, `group`, etc are all Ruby methods.